# Testing HTTP Requests that require a cookie

Tags: zend-framework2, phpunit

I am trying to setup unit tests for all of my HTTP requests. Every request requires authentication, and with my app it requires authentication via cookie & DB query.

I have a preDispatch method in a parent controller that looks like this:

```
        $this->cookie = Cookie::readCookie();
        if (is_null($this->cookie))
        {
            return $this->failResponseView();
        }

        $this->dm = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.documentmanager.odm_default');

        //Does not have authoriziation
        if (!$this->hasAppAccess())
        {
            return $this->failResponseView();
        }
```

This has been working fine as far as the app is concerned. But running `phpunit` fails everytime because the cookie can't be read, or the response is being written before it is read.

This is me mirroring what I do in the regular app, in my test setup method:

```
$this->_cookie = new Cookie(array('access_token' => $profile['token']));
$this->_cookie->setCookie();
```

However, I receive this `Exception` when the code reaches this point. My question is, how can I fake, or bypass my cookie authentication when running `phpunit` to make sure all of these authenticated requests work?

```
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at D:
\www\app\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\Util\Printer.php:172)
```

**UPDATE**

It looks like since the PHPUnit\Util\Printer is outputting to STDOUT (see above), it's not liking that I am trying to write a cookie. Running this allowed full execution

`phpunit --stderr`

So I am able to call the setCookie() method, and it executes fine. But when I get to the point where it does `Cookie::readCookie()`, even though it's already been set, it can't read it. It returns null.

So question is still pretty much the same. What do I do to test this app if it uses cookie authentication?

Comment: What is `Cookie`? That doesn't look like a ZF class.

Comment: @TimFountain it's just a custom class I created to store some info necessary for authentication. Where I run `setcookie()`. I have also updated my question with a little more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh, it's always something simple. In my setup method, I can just do this...

```
$_COOKIE[$name]= $this->_cookie->getData();
```